# QPlainTextEdit using around 6 times the memory of it's text

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, pyside

I have a small program here where I dump out 1,000,000 characters into QPlainTextEdit. When I look at SystemMonitor in linux to view my memory, I am seeing 90.8 M of memory! The text should only be around 1M. Why is QPlainTextEdit using so much memory?

I am using PySide 1.2.4, and QtCore version 4.6.2.

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.show()
        self.lines = ''
        for i in range(100000):
            self.insertPlainText('0123456789\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit( ret )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because your program uses more memory than just text. You could just run this code then check your memory:

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
w.show()
ret = app.exec_()
```

In my machine, it takes around 30MB memory. It's only a empty widget, do nothing. And if I run your code, it takes even 110MB larger than you!

You must know, QWidget carries a lot of metadata you can't see them, but they always exists.